PySpark tz_localize_to_utc error: NonExistentTimeError
My Glue PySpark code failes due to date issue:
pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 2024-03-31 01:15:00
pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 2023-03-26 01:03:00

Snippet of code:
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Europe/London")

final_data_renamed = (
    final_data.transform(
        rename_columns(
            suffix=f"{args.<val_1>}_abc_{args.<val_2>}w",
        )
    ).withColumn("datetimeiso", col("datetimeiso").cast("string")).withColumn(date_col, col(date_col).cast("timestamp"))
)

final_data_renamed.write.mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").format("parquet").save(
    file_path,
    header=True,
)

I having issue to grasp why this NonExistentTimeError comes up.
Great thanks for any hints on this!
